# rake specific test succeeds but rake all tests fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rake

I would like to share this problem with you as I spent almost a full day trying to figure out what the problem was:

I had a controller test running fine when started as a single test

```
rake test test/controller/pcp_subjects_controller_1_test.rb
```

but when I ran all my tests using simply 'rake', this test failed all the time.
The problem - as it turned out - was that I had three tests (files) for the same controller (pcp_subjects_controller) but in two files used the **identical** class name (that happens when you do copy/paste ;-):

```
class PcpSubjectsController1Test < ActionController::TestCase
  tests PcpSubjectsController

  setup do
    ...
  end

  test 'my test case' do
    ...
  end

end
```

Now this is no problem if you run a test as single test. But if you run both files at the same time, the test cases will be mixed - **and** both setup code will run for **all** test cases!

If someone has an idea how to ensure that each test file has a unique class name, I would appreciate a hint so I can prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I should add a standard test case with a standard name? If I would use the same class name in another file, it would give me the error that the test name is already used.